# Only 12 Transaction/s on Causal Cluster

Tags: neo4j

I deployed Neo4J on a cluster of 3 machines and execute a code that is supposed to stress-test the cluster.

For instance, here is the function that delete all node :

```
public void deleteAllNode()
    {
        try
        {
            while (amountNode() > 0) {
            session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public String execute( Transaction tx )
                {
                    tx.run( "START nx=node(*) WITH nx LIMIT 1 DETACH DELETE nx");
                    return "Node Deleted";
                }
            } );
       }
       }finally {   
       }
    }
```

Sadly this code only perform to execute 12 transactions/s. I believe the same code on a local single instance machine was 20 times faster.

Also here is the code of AmountNode():

```
public int amountNode(){
        try
        {
             StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (n) RETURN count(*)");
             if(result.hasNext()){
                 return result.next().get(0).asInt();
             }
        return 0;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

If someone has a better way to calculate how many nodes are in the graph, feel free to share.

Also here is how i'm establishing the connection before calling the function :

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri1 , AuthTokens.basic(user, password) );
session = driver.session(AccessMode.WRITE);
```

Any help welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that issuing a separate transaction per individual node delete to test deletion of all nodes in the graph is going to be terribly inefficient.

You should either delete all at once (using `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n`) or batch delete using APOC Procedures for this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (n) RETURN n', 'DETACH DELETE n', {})
```

Also, the START syntax is deprecated, please avoid using it.

You also haven't described your data at all. Remember that `DETACH DELETE` doesn't just delete the node, it deletes all relationships connected to that node. Deleting a single relationship with tens of thousands of relationships may be doing as much work as deleting tens of thousands of relationship-less nodes. Also indexes must be updated during these operations, so there is often more work being done under the hood than you may realize.

Comment: I kind of knew deleting the node one by one was inefficient, I did it this way to test the speed of the cluster. And, apparently it can only handle 12 transactions/seconds.  Can you confirm it's normal behavior ? Knowing that the average relationship with a each node is 3. And there is, overall, very little data in the graph itself.

Comment: 12 tx/sec sounds far too low. You also haven't provided some of the specs for this cluster. Are you using SSDs or spinning disks? How much RAM does each have? What are your pagecache and heap settings? Has the pagecache warmed up? [Here's a performance section](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/) that may help for ensuring ideal configuration.

Comment: The clusters are running on i7 / HDD with 8Go of RAM each. I left the other parameters that you mention at the default configuration. Thanks for the performance guide, I will check it out.